# Can't declare variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to migrate from MSSQL to MySQL. I have been having issues with and scripts I run that use declare, in that I can't figure out how to make it work at all. On MSSQL I have a few scripts like this:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @myValue AS NVARCHAR(64);
// Do stuff
END
```

In MySQL the [DECLARE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html) doesn't seem to require the as keyword but should do the same thing:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @myValue VARCHAR(64);
// Do stuff
END
```

When this code is placed in the Workbench it tells me that "DECLARE (declare) is not valid input at this position" and when I attempt to run it I get an Error Code 1064 "near 'DECLARE @myValue VARCHAR(64)' at line 2"

Comment: Are you running these in a stored procedure or function, or just trying to do this in an ad hoc query?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support stand alone blocks: you have to put them in a procedure or a function.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski At the moment, just in a query.